Question related to Cauchy distribution ratio symmetry
Let X and Y be i.i.d. random variables that follow standard normal distribution N(0, 1). Then can you prove the following equation?
$P(\frac{X}{Y} < t) = P(\frac{X}{|Y|} < t)$.
And also can you explain intuitively why are they equal?
